# Create postgres statement trigger after UPDATE using data from the update to call NOTIFY

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'd like to create a trigger that runs whenever an `INSERT` statement on a table succeeded, using the data from the insert to call `pg_notify`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_updates() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(NEW.aggregate_type, NEW.aggregate_id::text);
    RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER model_notification
 AFTER INSERT ON events
 FOR EACH STATEMENT
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_updates()
```

`aggregate_type` and `aggregate_id` are columns of the `events` table. the values for `aggregate_type` are known in advance and it's possible to call `LISTEN` on the relevant channels in advance.

The error I get says "channel name cannot be empty". I guess it's because the trigger runs for each statement and not for each row.
Is there a way to make this work for statement triggers? I think the interesting part is that there might be a couple of rows that were inserted and postgres doesn't know which value it should choose?

This question is similar to [Using row data in pg_notify trigger as channel name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768976/using-row-data-in-pg-notify-trigger-as-channel-name), but I want to have the trigger run on each statement instead of each row because in my particular case the values for `aggregate_type` and `aggregate_id` will be the same for all rows on each insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a transition table:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_updates() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
   BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_notify(aggregate_type, aggregate_id::text)
      FROM new_table -- transition table
      LIMIT 1;       -- !!
    RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER model_notification
 AFTER INSERT ON events
 REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_table -- define transition table name
 FOR EACH STATEMENT
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_updates();
```

Read more about the feature in the documentation:

- [Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html)
- [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

Transition tables were introduced in Postgres 10. Read also [Trigger that will build one row from several rows.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53384095/1995738)

Comment: I completely missed the first link to the docs, that was helpful. I also had to do another cast for aggregate_type to text (it's a varchar column), which in turn requires me to add quotes in the LISTEN command. That's ok for now as a workaround and beyond the scope of this question here